# I cant pass variables between loops using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, sql, variables, nested-loops

In the loops below, PHP doesn't seem to pass the outputted string back out to the loop that contains it for further manipulation, then making the output from this loop nothing at all.

Please help me understand why this is...

```
<?php

$finalTablePrint = '<html><body style="font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:40px;">
                        LTU Activity Report<br/>
                        <span style="font-size:18px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date Created: ' . date("l jS \of F Y") . '<br/><br/>
                        <table width=100% style="background-color:white; font-size:12px; border-collapse:collapse;" >
                        <tr style="font-size:12px; font-weight:600; background-color:#d2dbdf; height:35px;">
                            <td>Activity</td><td>Department</td><td>Hours Spent</td><td>Month</td>
                        </tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $finalTablePrint .= '<tr><td colspan=4>' . $row['activity'] . '</td></tr>';
    while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row_1['activity'] == $row['activity'] && $row_1['department'] == $row['department']) {
            $finalTablePrint .= '<tr style="height:30px;"><td colspan=3>' . $row['department'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['hours'] . '</td><td>' . $row['month'] . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}

echo $finalTablePrint .='</table><script type="text/javascript">javascript:window.print(); setTimeout(\'window.location="../../admin/index.php"\',"1000");</script></body></html>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you set off your second loop, you are calling the same SQL statement as the original one before it

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   //1st while
while ($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    //2nd while
```

which in turn means that this if statement will allways be true....

```
 if ($row_1['activity'] == $row['activity'] && $row_1['department'] == $row['department']) {
```

and this will allways echo:

```
  $finalTablePrint .= '<tr style="height:30px;"><td colspan=3>'.$row['department'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['hours'].'</td><td>'.$row['month'].'</td></tr>';
```

so you should really remove your 2nd while/if statement... since it achieves nothing at the moment

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't even click to that issue?!

Comment: Wait doesnt the second loop, loops through all items in the list comparing them to the item from the outside loop?

Comment: no? how can it you are putting identical select statement and running it within itself, how does that achieve unique results to if statement?

Comment: i think i see what you mean, im going to try a different approach using array_unique... thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because js script at the end navigates you away too quickly you have no chance to see what happened! Remove it until you fix things the way you like it, and make sure that js is doing exactly what you are asking for.